# legend overwrites chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart with many series. I placed the legend with series names below the chart. The problem is that I cannot know in advance which is the height of the legend, and sometimes it happens to be soo large that it overwrites the graph above.

Is it possible to adapt the size of the graph to the size of the legend in javascript code? Best solution for me would be to keep fixed the size of the graph and enlarge the height of enclosing  element.

**edit:**
a jsfiddle which resembles my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/KfWDD/1/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({     
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE
    }, {
        name: 'MSFT',
        data: MSFT
    }]
});
```

I would like to have the legend below the navigator. I can obtain this by fixing some margins and offsets in the elements, but then the layout breaks if the legend becomes too tall.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [maxHeight](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.maxHeight) for the legend, and add fixed [margin](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.margin) to make some space for that legend.

Comment: The problem seem to be the interaction between the legend and the navigator. I added a jsfiddle to play with. I don't understand how 'margin' and 'y' act precisely.

Comment: I solved the problem by setting ´floating: False´, otherwise the offset of the navigator bar would anyway depend on the size of the legend